# Как сделать такой круг на css?

Tags: html, css

[image]

Как сделать круг, с красным кругом внутри, расположенным по центру и толстой, целостной обводкой снаружи, которая немного бледнее цвета, самого круга?

Comment: [radial-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Using_CSS_gradients#%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  background: black;
}

div {
  width: 70vmin;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: radial-gradient(red, red 40%, transparent calc(40% + 1px)) #8888;
  border: .5em solid #888A;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
    .round{
        width:40px;
        height:40px;
        background: #ff0000;
        border-radius: 50%;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #434344;
        border:30px solid #29292A;
    }
```

```html
<div class="round"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Мой вариант))

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
.round {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:linear-gradient(to right, #2A2A2A 0, #2A2A2A 44%, #2E2F2F 50%, #2A2A2A 55%, #2A2A2A 100%);
  border: 7px solid #434343;
  position: relative;
}
.round:before {
  content: '';
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #F23849;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="round"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно приблизительно как-то так сделать:

```css
body,
.big-circle,
.midl-circle {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}

.big-circle,
.midl-circle,
.litl-circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.big-circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgb(143, 158, 181);
}

.midl-circle {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: rgba(82, 90, 105, .8);
}

.litl-circle {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: rgb(245, 59, 59);
}
```

```html
<div class="big-circle">
  <div class="midl-circle">
    <div class="litl-circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```